# Disable cmd+k when using Vim in terminal?

Tags: macos, vim, terminal

So when I'm using Vim in the mac osx terminal I accidentally enter the command cmd+k that clears my terminal because I'm used to the motion, this makes me have to exit vim and enter again. I want to know if theres a way to disable this.

For example this is me editing my .vimrc

[image]

Then I enter the command and my terminal looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to disable this command when using Vim only? I want to continue using it when using the terminal outside Vim. Thanks

Comment: Instead of restarting vim try [CTRL-L](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#CTRL-L) to redraw the screen.

Comment: @phd That seems to work fine, please submit your comment as an answer so that I can check it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for asking this. I do this regularly, and it's oddly absent from discussion whenever I've searched for the command (where is it in the docs?). Usually you need to mentally translate `cmd` to `ctrl` when using vim on a Mac, but here `ctrl+k` doesn't perform the task, but `ctrl+l` undoes it. I've tried displaying all key mappings or getting help for CMD-K from within vim, but get no results. Anybody have a doc link for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of restarting vim use [CTRL-L](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#CTRL-L) to redraw the screen.

Comment: It helps, but it doesn't really fix the problem. I still need to manually ctrl-l when I accidentally cmd-k. Is it possible to disable cmd-k completely? I use option-k as the vim "up" key, and I accidentally click cmd instead of option because of the poor keyboard ergonomics.

Comment: Also doesn't seem to work if I am in vim in a tmux session